# Oneplus5 Lineage OS 15.1 kernel compilation

Tags: android, linux-kernel, toolchain, rom

I am trying to compile kernel for Oneplus5 with Lineage OS 15.1 custom ROM installed. I am using google ndk toolchains for compiling kernel. I extracted the kernel source code from Lineage OS source code, also tried compiling stock ROM kernel.

After few heat and trials and fixing some files in the source code of kernel finally I managed to compile it successfully! After compilation is completed I got Image,Image.gz files in arch/arm64/boot directory.

But when I tried to flash the kernel image from TWRP recovery, device always boot into fastboot mode and got stuck there. What is the issue and what can I do to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `mka bootimage`, then flashing the resulting `boot.img` with `fastboot flash boot boot.img`.

The slightly longer version, based on the instructions at https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/cheeseburger/build:

```
apt install adb fastboot bc bison build-essential ccache curl flex g++-multilib gcc-multilib git gnupg gperf imagemagick lib32ncurses5-dev lib32readline-dev lib32z1-dev liblz4-tool libncurses5-dev libsdl1.2-dev libssl-dev libwxgtk3.0-dev libxml2 libxml2-utils lzop pngcrush rsync schedtool squashfs-tools xsltproc zip zlib1g-dev openjdk-8-jdk python unzip

mkdir -p ~/bin
mkdir -p ~/android/lineage

curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
chmod a+x ~/bin/repo

echo 'PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"' >> .profile
echo 'export LC_ALL=C' >> .profile

git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"

cd ~/android/lineage
repo init -u https://github.com/LineageOS/android.git -b lineage-15.1
repo sync

source build/envsetup.sh
# use extract-files.sh or follow https://gist.github.com/fourkbomb/261ced58cd029c5f7742350aafdd9825
breakfast cheeseburger

mka bootimage
```

If the `mka bootimage` step runs without errors but doesn't generate a `boot.img`, try running `mka bacon` for a few minutes, then abort it and re-run `mka bootimage`.

The above commands will use LineageOS' default kernel for the device, in `./android/lineage/kernel/oneplus/msm8998`. You can simply make your changes there, or place a whole new kernel source in that directory. In the latter case, make sure to place a `lineage_oneplus5_defconfig` file in `arch/arm64/configs`.